# rsync bullies destination ACLs for fun

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rsync, file-permissions, acl

I have the following ACLs configured on a directory (`.ssh`) at the destination of my rsync:

```
# file: .ssh
# owner: jsmith
# group: jsmith
user::rwx
user:backup:r-x
group::---
group:backup:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:backup:r-x
default:group::---
default:group:backup:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

I am using `rsync` with the options `-aXzv` to transfer the `.ssh` directory between two servers, and after the transfer, the destination has the following ACLs:

```
# file: .ssh
# owner: jsmith
# group: jsmith
user::rwx
user:backup:r-x            #effective:---
group::---
group:backup:r-x           #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:backup:r-x
default:group::---
default:group:backup:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

The source directory has these ACLs:

```
# file: .ssh
# owner: jsmith
# group: jsmith
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

**Notice the destination `mask` has changed from `r-x` (before the rsync) to `---` (after the rsync).**

Why is this happening, and how can I use rsync to retain the source user, group, and other permissions while preserving the destination's extended ACLs such that the `backup` user has full execute and write permissions after the rsync operation?

EDIT: Both servers are running rsync 3.0.9, both server filesystems have ACLs enabled. The source server uses ext3 and the destination server uses ext4.

Answer (score 3):

The destination mask is changed to `---` because you're running rsync with the `-a` option, which implies `-p`/`--perms`. What this means is that `rsync` will try to preserve the source's permissions, which then effectively tries to do a `chmod 700` on the destination. See https://serverfault.com/questions/352783/why-does-chmod1-on-the-group-affect-the-acl-mask/352915#352915 for an explanation of why changing the group permission with `chmod` will change the ACL mask.

As for respecting destination ACLs and preserving access to the "backup" group, maybe running with `--no-p --chmod=g=rwX`? This will create new files using the directory's default ACL, and update files without changing their permissions -- that is, it will only work if the existing files permissions aren't to change.